# Is there an Oracle DB 11g or 10g available for Mac osx?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have searched high and low and can't seem to find any download for Oracle Database 10/11g for Mac OSX. There area pages with links, but all the links are dead or point to the standard oracle downloads with no OSX version.

Is there an Oracle DB 11g or 10g available for Mac osx? If so, where is it?

Comment: You could always run in it an VM on Linux

Comment: @horse I am doing that, but there are issues with connectivity from eclipse to the DB on the vm, plus it would be a lot cleaner if it was on the same machine. The odd thing is that there are lots of install tutorials, but all relating to 10g, however I can't find any version for mac.

Comment: Discussion is a bit old.
But I want to update this thread.
There is good article for this question.
http://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/how-to-install-oracle-database-on-mac-os-any-version/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

once upon a time there was a 10.2.4.0 download at http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/oracle10g/htdocs/10204macsoft_x86-64.html .  Some people got it to work with the help of [this blog post](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/) , but I never got it to work.
Oracle says,

> "Oracle Database 10.2 and 11.1 are no longer available for download.
> The software is available as a media or FTP request for those
> customers who own a valid Oracle Database product license for any
> edition. To request access to these releases, follow the instructions
> in Oracle Support Document 1071023.1 (Requesting Physical Shipment or
> Download URL for Software Media) from My Oracle Support."

So, the long answer is - it's possible to get it going but truly doubtful that it's worth your effort.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to setup oracle on the VM , here is a link about how to go about based on my personal experience
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Th5MSIhS13YIJYCD8W1GLnOQEfrfov-92-He1cluTec/pub

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same question as you and wondered for a while. Finally I managed to install 11gR2 using VirtualBox and [wrote a detailed blog post describing the process](http://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/how-to-install-oracle-database-on-mac-os-any-version/) first about 11gR2 and recently updated for 12cR1.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 11g is available for:

- Microsoft Windows (32-bit)
- Microsoft Windows (x64)
- Linux x86
- Linux x86-64
- Solaris (SPARC)
- Solaris (x86-64)
- HP-UX Itanium
- HP-UX PA-RISC (64-bit)
- AIX (PPC64) zLinux64

But not for Mac OSX.

See this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen).

Comment: This is the page that the links keep forwarding me to. I guess I was hoping that there was some forgotten link somewhere that someone might be able to point me too? Or perhaps an old mirror of 10g for mac osx.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Oracle should release a version of Oracle 11g for Mac OS too. If they are making a version of Oracle Virtual Box then they should have also the need of making a version of Oracle 11g or 12c for Mac OS.